# Filling in HTML form with __RequestVerificationToken using Java

Tags: java, html, angular, csrf-protection

I am building an app that uses stored login/pass information to login to a website and scrape its content. However, the frontend of the concerned website has changed and now my scripts don't work anymore.

I've discovered that the website now employs a more sophisticated login procedure using some kind of CSRF Protection. I already extracted the relevant __RequestVerificationToken from the website but can't submit the form. This is the HTML code of the form that I am trying to fill in using a JAVA tool:

```
<form name="userInfoForm" ng-submit="$ctrl.signIn(userInfoForm)" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group">
      <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.responseModel.errorMessage -->    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only">
        Username
      </label>
      <input id="kitnum-input" tabindex="1" type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" placeholder="Username" ng-model="$ctrl.kitNum" ng-change="$ctrl.onType(userInfoForm)" autofocus="" required=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only">
        Password
      </label>
      <input id="password-input" tabindex="2" type="password" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" placeholder="Password" ng-model="$ctrl.password" ng-change="$ctrl.onType(userInfoForm)" required=""/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group text-center cta-space cta">
    <button id="sign-in-btn" type="submit" value="Sign in" data-style="zoom-in" class="btn btn-main btn-uppercase ladda-button" loading-data-button="" loading="false" ng-disabled="$ctrl.submitDisabled" disabled="disabled">
      <span class="ladda-label">
        Sign In
      </span>
      <span class="ladda-spinner">
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And this the current JAVA code:
        HtmlPage landing_page = null;

```
    webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);

     webClient.getCache().setMaxSize(0);
     final HtmlPage loginpage = webClient.getPage(this.login_url);

     List<HtmlForm> forms_from_login_page = loginpage.getForms();
     HtmlForm form_from_login_page = forms_from_login_page.get(0);

     String token = get__RequestVerificationToken(loginpage.asXml());
     WebRequest web_req = loginpage.getWebResponse().getWebRequest();
     web_req.setAdditionalHeader("__RequestVerificationToken", token);

     HtmlTextInput userNameTextField = loginpage.getHtmlElementById("user-input");
     HtmlPasswordInput passwordTextField = loginpage.getHtmlElementById("password-input");

     userNameTextField.setValueAttribute(this.profile_id);
     passwordTextField.setValueAttribute(this.password);

     DomElement button = loginpage.getElementById("sign-in-btn");
     button.setAttribute("type", "submit");
     landing_page = button.click();
```

Any ideas how to tackle this?